# My fields don't appear in views after doing mymodule_views_data()

Tags: views, entities, database

I've created a table in mymodule .install file.

function secciones_schema() {

```
$schema['seccion_empresa_contenido'] = array(
        'description' => 'Contenido de la seccion de tipo "Categoría de empresa"',
        'fields' => array(
                'id_revista' => array(
                        'description' => t('id de la revista asociada'),
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'length' => 10,
                ),
                'id_seccion' => array(
                        'description' => t('id de la seccion'),
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'length' => 10,
                ),
                'color' => array(
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 10,
                ),
                'imagen' => array(
                        'type' => 'int',
                ),
                'nombre' => array(
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'length' => 40,
                ),
                'nombreEu' => array(
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'length' => 40,
                ),
                'titleColor' => array(
                        'description' => t('Color del titulo'),
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'length' => 3,
                ),
                'fecha_inicio'=> array(
                         'mysql_type' => 'DATETIME',
                ),
                'fecha_fin'=> array(
                         'mysql_type' => 'DATETIME',
                         'default'=>NULL,
                ),



        ),
        'primary key' => array('id_seccion','fecha_inicio'),
);



return $schema;
```

}

I need to show this fields in a view. So I've added to my module mymodule.views.inc file with the next code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function secciones_views_data() {
  $data['seccion_empresa_contenido'] = array(
  'table' => array(
    'base' => array(
      'field' => 'id_seccion',
      'title' => 'Seccion Empresa Contenido',
      'help' => 'Contenido de la seccion de tipo "Categoría de empresa"',
    ),
    'group' => 'Seccion Empresa Contenido',
  ),
  'id_revista' => array(
    'title' => 'Id Revista',
    'help' => 'id de la revista asociada',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'id_seccion' => array(
    'title' => 'Id Seccion',
    'help' => 'id de la seccion',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'color' => array(
    'title' => 'Color',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'imagen' => array(
    'title' => 'Imagen',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'nombre' => array(
    'title' => 'Nombre',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'nombreEU' => array(
    'title' => 'NombreEU',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'titleColor' => array(
    'title' => 'TitleColor',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'fecha_inicio' => array(
    'title' => 'Fecha Inicio',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
      ),
  ),
  'fecha_fin' => array(
    'title' => 'Fecha Fin',
    'help' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
      ),
  ),
);
    return $data;
}
```

In mymodule.module file I have the next function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function secciones_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => '3.5',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'secciones'),
  );
}
```

And finaly, In my .info file I have added the new file:

```
files[] = secciones.views.inc
```

Ok, so after doing that it is supossed to appear the new field in views, isn't it?
It doesn't appear anything. Does anybody know if I'm doing any mistake in the code or maybe this is not the way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: hook_views_data makes you a whole new view, not a field

Comment: Ok. So in structure/views I have to see a view that is seccion_empresa_contenido isn't it? I don't see anything...

Comment: It's not exact: `hook_view_data()` is for integrating a module's data into view. It doesn't build any view.

Comment: true - sorry, messed up with `hook_views_default_views`,  was a too quick look. to see your field(s) you need to work on a view based on your entity type or all !

Comment: And how can I do that? Is there any hook or I can do it from Views UI?